Jackson Object Mapper readTree with boolean values
{
   "data":{
      "id":"550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000",
      "timestamp":"2023-05-01T16:34:16.993007076Z",
      "isProcessed":true,
      "isFailed":false
   }
}

and i would like deserialize it using jackson object mapper to:
{
   "data":{
      "id":"550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000",
      "timestamp":"2023-05-01T16:34:16.993007076Z",
      "isProcessed":"true",
      "isFailed":"false"
   }
}

Do I need add some deserializer to object mapper? My code:
val data: JsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(logEvent)
saveData(data) // Store as jsonb


You could read the JSON into a TokenBuffer, transforming booleans to strings as they are parsed:
fun ObjectMapper.readTreeWithStringyBooleans(json: String): JsonNode {
    this.createParser(json).use { parser ->
        TokenBuffer(parser).use { tokenBuffer ->
            while (true) {
                val token = parser.nextToken() ?: break
                when (token) {
                    JsonToken.VALUE_TRUE -> tokenBuffer.writeString("true")
                    JsonToken.VALUE_FALSE -> tokenBuffer.writeString("false")
                    else -> tokenBuffer.copyCurrentEvent(parser)
                }
            }
            return this.readTree(tokenBuffer.asParser())
        }
    }
}

Usage:
val json = """
{
   "data":{
      "id":"550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000",
      "timestamp":"2023-05-01T16:34:16.993007076Z",
      "isProcessed":true,
      "isFailed":false
   }
}
"""

val tree = objectMapper.readTreeWithStringyBooleans(json)
println(
    objectMapper
        .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
        .writeValueAsString(tree)
)

Prints:
{
  "data" : {
    "id" : "550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000",
    "timestamp" : "2023-05-01T16:34:16.993007076Z",
    "isProcessed" : "true",
    "isFailed" : "false"
  }
}

